# IPN - PAYPAL No Return POST Data on Mobile

Tags: post, mobile, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

Many people are struggling with this one, when getting the return from PayPal there is no POST data if you use a mobile device (fine on desktop), so you can not run the IPN as there is no data to send.

What do PayPal expect us to do, I have contacted PayPal support but they have not answered, this is crazy, why would it work differently?

Has anyone resolved this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does you mean that there is no POST data if you use a mobile device.
Can you discribe the details.

PayPal IPN will always be sent to you if you set it up in your account.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

Comment: if you use mobile device, paypal will not return any of ipn post data to success page.